# Most efficient way to check all conditions in if statement?

Tags: java, algorithm

So I'm trying to do this if statement for multiple conditions where in order for the password to qualify it should meet 4 out of 5 things. I get an error saying

The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Note: the error occurs at the bottom of my method,(if statement error)

```
      public void passRequirments(){


        int digit,symbol,upper,lower;
        int countDigit, countSymbol,countUpper,countLower;
        countDigit = 0;
        countSymbol= 0;
        countUpper = 0;
        countLower = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < passChar.length; i++){
        digit = (int)passChar[i] ;
        symbol = (int)passChar[i];
        upper  = (int)passChar[i];
        lower  = (int)passChar[i];

        if(digit >=48 && digit <= 57){
          countDigit = 1;
          System.out.println(countDigit);
        }
        else if(symbol >=32 && symbol <= 47 || symbol >=58 && symbol <= 64 ||
                symbol >=91 && symbol <= 96 || symbol >=123 && symbol <= 126){
          countSymbol = 1;
          if (countSymbol == 1){

            System.out.println("hello");
          }
        }
        else if( upper >=65 &&  upper <= 90){
          countUpper = 1;
        }
        else {
          countLower = 1;
        }

 }
         //this is where i'm running into error

        if(passChar.length  >= 8  && countDigit == 1 && countSymbol && countUpper == 1 ||
          passChar.length >= 8 && countDigit == 1 && countSymbol && countLower == 1 ||
          passChar.length >= 8 && countDigit == 1 && countLower  && countUpper == 1 ||
          passChar.length >= 8 && countSymbol == 1 && countLower && countUpper == 1){

       System.out.println("Password Qualfies!");
       passwordScore = passwordScore + 10;

      }
      else {

       System.out.println("Password Doesn't Qualify!");


      }


  }
```

Comment: You have `&& countSymbol` and `&& countLower`, these are `int`s. You can't do `&&` on `int`s, only on `boolean`s.

Comment: What? I dont understand

Comment: `countLower == 1` is a `boolean` - either `true` or `false`. `countLower ` is an `int` - a number. The things between `&&` need to be `boolean`s.

Comment: `Character.isAlphabetic(symbol)`.

Comment: Beyond that simple typo: the real problem with your code is the fact that it is overly complicated. You could express this with much less code that would be much easier to understand. You should step back and identify the common aspects in your code and avoid repeating them.

Comment: @GhostCat hahahahah Omg I'm so dumb :( and yeah for sure thanks tho you got my mistake

Comment: Nobody is dumb. I am just putting up the next challenge for you :-)   seriously: most people can write code that the compiler understands and that actually does what it is supposed to do. The interesting part is to write code that doesn't need to be thrown away and rewritten come the need for enhancing it. Code that other humans can read and understand without reading it 10 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, the parameter inside if statement should be strictly `boolean`.

I see that you're checking simply for `countSymbol` instead it should be `countSymbol == 0` or `countSymbol > 0` as per your requirement.

```
if(passChar.length  >= 8  && countDigit == 1 && countSymbol==0 && countUpper == 1 ||
                                                     ^ change this
```

Make similar changes in other `Or` conditions as well

Comment: Thank you soo much you also caught my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If by `countSymbol && countUpper == 1` you are trying to say that both `countSymbol` **and** countUpper should be equal to 1, that's not how `&&` works.  You have to write out both conditions in full: `countSymbol == 1 && countUpper == 1`.  Same with `countLower  && countUpper == 1`.

Fun fact:  a notation similar to that would have worked if you were writing in COBOL :)